# why new is optional in the following jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Reading docs of JQuery, we could construct the event object by

```
//Create a new jQuery.Event object without the "new" operator.
var e = jQuery.Event( "click" );
```

I am wondering why we could construct Event without using new? This is counterintuitive for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing the function does is:

> ```
> if (! (this instanceof jQuery.Event)) {
>     return new jQuery.Event(src, props);
> }
> ```

If you aren't creating an Event object, it creates one (passing along the arguments you passed in) and then returns it so the first invoke of the Event function does nothing further.